# What is the compiler version of a contract created by internal transaction?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, compiler

I want to be able to verify and publish a contract source code on Etherscan.io.
I have created a new contract from a factory contract, in which I successfully published and verified.
When I come to fill the corresponding form for verifying and publishing the newly created contract on Etherscan.io, it fails.
Possibly, the reason is a mismatch in the compiler version (other fields such as the contract name are surely correct).

So, what compiler version does one use for an internal transaction which created a contract?
Should it be the same one as the one used to compile the parent (factory) contract?